# How to implement left outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have this query i want to implement left outer join how can i do it

```
SELECT A.cl_id, A.cl_name, A.number_of_orders, B.Dispatch
FROM (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id, CL_Clients.cl_name,COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
    FROM CL_Clients,CLOI_ClientOrderItems
    WHERE CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id
    ) A
, (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id,count(*) AS Dispatch
    FROM CLOI_ClientOrderItems,CL_Clients
    WHERE cloi_current_status = '12'  
        AND CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id, CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cloi_current_status
    ) B

WHERE A.cl_id = B.cl_id
```

expected output

```
Cl_id    | Cl_name       |Builtorder |Dispatch
------------------------------------------------
admin    |admin 1    |0      |20
agar     |Agar Murdoch   |102        |1 
Alexander|Alexander James|33         |65    
alexandra|Alexandra West |64         |14    
Archer   |Archer & Co    |0      |5
asbank   |Stirling       |80         |8 
asnapebr |Andrew Snape   |183        |1 
asnapech |Andrew Snape Ch|213        |0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your full query can be written in very few line,Please try below code.

First Way, Single Join that is ALL !!!

```
Select a.cl_id
        ,a.cl_name
        ,count(b.cl_id) as number_of_orders
        ,Sum(Case When b.cloi_current_status ='12' 
                           --and Condition1 and condition2
                     Then 1 else 0 end) as Dispatch
    from CL_Clients as a
    left join CLOI_ClientOrderItems as b on a.cl_id = b.cl_id
 group by a.cl_id
        ,a.cl_name
```

Second way, multiple joins

```
Select a.cl_id
        ,a.cl_name
        ,Isnull(orderTable.orders,0) as number_of_orders
        ,ISNULL(dTable.Dispatch,0) as Dispatch
    from CL_Clients as a
    outer apply 
        (
            select b.cl_id,count(b.cl_id) as orders from  CLOI_ClientOrderItems as b 
            where a.cl_id = b.cl_id 
            group by b.cl_id
        )as orderTable 
    outer apply
        (
            select d.cl_id,count(*) as Dispatch from CLOI_ClientOrderItems as d
            where a.cl_id = d.cl_id
                and d.cloi_current_status ='12' 
                --and condition2
                --and condition3
                --..............
                --and condition250
            group by a.cl_id
        )as dTable
```

In above statement,
First join as `orderTable`  is used to get number of orders.
Second join as `dTableis` used to get number of orders which are dispatched, it can contain multiple Conditions as you have asked for, `-----Condition2 .....` is dummy text you can remove all comments like `Condition2,Condition3` ... & put your actual conditions.

Comment: Don't you need a `group by` clause?

Comment: @David, oops! Thank you friend, I missed it in hurry, ans updated.

Comment: @David, Thanks for your help also friend.

Comment: your using case tight in that b.cloi_current_status ='12' i have 250 condition how to do it

Comment: @user3514896,really? do you have 250 conditions? If yes then any how you want to put them in where clause. Sot it is up to you, if not in Case , then you need to apply one more join including all 250 conditions.Let me know if you want that way too.

Comment: @user3514896, which DBMS you are using? MySQL or MS SQL?

Comment: @user3514896, hope second way is what you are looking for.

Comment: i am not getting properly pls explain me

Comment: @pls check updated ans. Are you getting any error?Pls share you database schema & sample data. I will try to implement it on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: one one more thing if i put where condition it will not display it other coulmn.

Comment: And what does that mean?

Comment: i have image how can i share u??

Comment: Edit you question & you can put image over there.

Comment: it is asking 10 reputation means

Comment: Means you can't do it!. Instead of Image can you share some code of create table & insert into statements?

Comment: Please check I have modified 1st query also, in Case statement you can write multiple conditions.

Comment: I have a two tables CL_Clients and CLOI_ClientOrderItems.
in CL_Clients contains column cl_id(pk),cl_name and CLOI_ClientOrderItems contains column cl_id(fk) cloi_current_status.cloi_current_status is contains the number 0,1,2,3,4,5....250
in that 0 indicates dispatch,1indicates orderbuilt like till 250

Comment: Ok, sou you have different 250 status of Order, Right?

Comment: and you want count how may orders are there on each status?

Comment: yes exactly and one more thing in CL_Clients table cl_id contains 100000_Dpo,100010_Ond id's i dont want display Dpo and Ond extension id..

Comment: It would be great if you can share some dummy data, with expected output.

Comment: hi i got ans thanku one more help i have table  CL_Clients in that cl_id contains 100000_Dpo,100010_Ond id's i dont want display Dpo and Ond extension id..

Comment: Use Select REPLACE(REPLACE(cl_id,'_Dpo',''),'_Ond ','') in select.

Comment: its not replacing full id its replacing only Dpo and Ond again its displaying all cl_id

Comment: So what you want to display? I thought value like '100000_Dpo','100010_Ond ' and you want to display like '100000','100010'.

Comment: cl_id column conatins  '100000_Dpo','100010_Ond ' and names like agra,manu,rakesh just i want to display names

Comment: So add a where condition cl_id not like '%_Dpo%' and cl_id not like '%_Ond%'

Comment: thank you very much from past no one slove the problem here but u slove my problem thank u

Comment: @user3514896, so are you happy with my ans? then you can mark my ans as UseFul.

Comment: ya very use ful if possible can u solve this "I have a two tables CL_Clients and CLOI_ClientOrderItems. in CL_Clients contains column cl_id(pk),cl_name and CLOI_ClientOrderItems contains column cl_id(fk) cloi_current_status.cloi_current_status is contains the number 0,1,2,3,4,5....250 in that 0 indicates dispatch,1indicates orderbuilt like till 250"

Comment: will you ans for that??

Comment: It would be great if you can share some dummy data, with expected output.

Comment: u got expected result??

Comment: may be, wait I am busy in some other work, will update my Ans.

Comment: friend can u reply for that??

Comment: surely, I am on my JOB , a bit busy, will update once free. Apologies for delay.

Comment: its k can u give ur email id pls

Comment: where is your email id i didnt find pls tellme

Comment: amolkshirsagar86@gmail.com    My Profile  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3322039/ak47

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it in TSQL, but @AK47 has the solution that solves your bigger problem.

```
SELECT A.cl_id, A.cl_name, A.number_of_orders, B.Dispatch
FROM (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id, CL_Clients.cl_name,COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
    FROM CL_Clients,CLOI_ClientOrderItems
    WHERE CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id
    ) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CL_Clients.cl_id,count(*) AS Dispatch
    FROM CLOI_ClientOrderItems,CL_Clients
    WHERE cloi_current_status = '12'  
        AND CL_Clients.cl_id = CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id
    GROUP BY CL_Clients.cl_name,CL_Clients.cl_id, CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cloi_current_status
    ) B
ON A.cl_id = B.cl_id
```